# Find filename of view template in Rails 3 based on action and format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm upgrading an old Rails 2.3 (I know, I know) which uses an external program to modify a PDF before rendering it for an action.  Therefore, it's necessary for the action to be able to determine the filename of the PDF source file, which is stored in the view template directory, which was done with:

```
view_paths.find_template(default_template_name(:show), :pdf).filename
```

However, this no longer works in Rails 3.  I've tried something like:

```
lookup_context.find :show, controller_name
```

But I can't find a way to specify the format, so that always returns the path for the HTML template (`app/views/name/show.html.erb`).  How can I get the filename of the template for the PDF format (`app/views/name/show.pdf`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though more complicated than I would like, I eventually found this, which seems to work:

```
ActionView::LookupContext.
  new(view_paths, {formats: :pdf}).
  find(:show, controller_name).
  identifier
```